# OpenNI: "Save calibration to file failed: This operation is invalid!"

Tags: calibration, kinect, openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I've been trying to use the SaveCalibrationDataToFile function in OpenNI but so far, it hasn't been going so well.  When I try to call it, it returns a

```
Save calibration to file failed: This operation is invalid!
```

Here's the few lines of code:

```
  if (g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().IsCalibrated(nId)){
      XnStatus nRetVal = g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().SaveCalibrationDataToFile(nId, calib.bin);
      if (nRetVal != XN_STATUS_OK)
          printf("Save calibration to file failed: %s\n", xnGetStatusString(nRetVal));
  }
```

I also downloaded someone else's calibration file and tried to load it, but it yielded the same "operation is invalid" message.  Anyone have any clues?

Thanks

Update: I tried installing ROS and OpenNI via source in order to use the newest version, but it still displays the horrid and vague "invalid" message.

Update2: I installed the latest unstable version of OpenNI and SaveCalibrationDataToFile works!  For anyone who wants to do that, http://groups.google.com/group/openni-dev/msg/6ac27daf08ac31a9 will prove to be very useful

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10668/openni:-%22save-calibration-to-file-failed:-this-operation-is-invalid!%22/) by [daaango](https://answers.ros.org/users/864/daaango/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-07-20

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoeRomano](https://answers.ros.org/users/34/joeromano/) on 2011-08-08**:
In main.cpp of NiUserTracker you'll notice several callback functions that occur when a new user is found (line 87), or pose detected (line 106). If you insert the call to LoadCalibration into either of these functions it should work. I would recommend replacing line 110 from PoseDetected with this

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-08**:
Also, is there a way to make it automatically load the data. From looking at the code, it seems as if I need to type in 'L' every time I want it to apply the saved data to users.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-08**:
Do you mean "UserCalibration_CalibrationEnd" or "UserCalibration_CalibrationComplete"? "UserCalibration_CalibrationStart" does not have this line.

**Comment by [JoeRomano](https://answers.ros.org/users/34/joeromano/) on 2011-08-08**:
g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().SaveCalibrationDataToFile(aUserIDs[i], XN_CALIBRATION_FILE_NAME);

**Comment by [daaango](https://answers.ros.org/users/864/daaango/) on 2011-08-08**:
To get it to save calibration, all you have to do is paste "g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().IsCalibrated(aUserIDs[i])" into the XN_CALLBACK_TYPE UserCalibration_CalibrationStart function, specifically after "g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().StartTracking(nId)" which is around line 130.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-08**:
From daaango's update, it seems as though this feature is already in the latest unstable version of OpenNI. All I want to know is what commands I need to use to get this to work.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-08**:
I installed the latest unstable version, but when I use the Sample-NiUserTracker, it does not automatically save the calibration. Is there a different program that I need to run to use it? Also, do I need to create a file on my own, or does it automatically create one?

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-08-06**:
It's nice to know this works with newer versions of openni :) you should answer the question yourself so that some admin can mark it as answered.

**Comment by [daaango](https://answers.ros.org/users/864/daaango/) on 2011-08-02**:
I was hoping it would maybe be a usage error on my part or something, but I guess deep down I had an inclination that it had something to do with openni...  Hopefully someone who deals with OpenNI integration in ROS will stumble upon this thread and provide some insight!

**Comment by [Miguel Prada](https://answers.ros.org/users/164/miguel-prada/) on 2011-08-01**:
I'm having the same issue, and the only thing I can think of is that this might be a OpenNI version issue. The only people I've heard that has been able to make it work used a more recent version of OpenNI. Hopefully when a newer version is released it will be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like it has to do with the ROS version of OpenNI, as saving to file works when using the unstable version of OpenNI.  Refer to the original post for a link to instructions on how to do that.

Special thanks to Miguel Prada and Asomerville!

---

edit: For those who wish to test this for themselves (specifically qdocehf cough cough), after installing OpenNI navigate to the folder OpenNI/Samples/NiUserTracker/ and copy the following files to a new directory: SceneDrawer.cpp
SceneDrawer.h main.cpp

Open up main.cpp and after line 146, paste

```
g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().SaveCalibrationDataToFile(nId, "calibration.bin")
```

and then compile the file with g++:

```
g++ -o NiUserTracker SceneDrawer.cpp main.cpp -I/usr/include/ni/ -l'OpenNI' -l'glut'
```

This will simply save the calibration of any user who performs the psi pose (continuously overwriting the .bin file).  This is meant to just be a quick demo to make sure saving calibration data to file works.  There is already a function on line 167 that is supposed to save calibration when the s key is pushed, but I must be using it wrong because I didn't get it working and don't really care for it enough to figure it out.

edit2: For testing loading calibration files, around line 90 of main.cpp, just paste in the following code:

```
g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().LoadCalibrationDataFromFile(nId, "calibration.bin");
g_UserGenerator.GetPoseDetectionCap().StopPoseDetection(nId);
g_UserGenerator.GetSkeletonCap().StartTracking(nId);
```

This will simply load up a calibration file as soon as a new user detected, so you'll want to fiddle around some more with code to make sure a calibration file is available, make sure its not requesting calibration after loading, etc...

---

Originally posted by [daaango](https://answers.ros.org/users/864/daaango/) with karma: 101 on 2011-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [daaango](https://answers.ros.org/users/864/daaango/) on 2011-08-09**:
you're right, sorry about that.  I deleted UserCalibration_CalibrationEnd completely from my version as its not called anywhere in the program.

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-09**:
Thanks. By the way, the main method in main.cpp uses UserCalibration_CalibrationComplete, not UserCalibration_CalibrationEnd. The safest thing to do would probably be to just paste the line into both methods.

**Comment by [daaango](https://answers.ros.org/users/864/daaango/) on 2011-08-08**:
check the post! I added a second edit

**Comment by [qdocehf](https://answers.ros.org/users/770/qdocehf/) on 2011-08-08**:
What about LoadCalibrationFromFile? The only place that I can find where it is called is when you push the 'L' key, but can it be done automatically? P.S. Sorry about asking so many questions.